# c++11 analog of C# StopWatch

Tags: c++

I'm looking for StopWatch class with microseconds precision. I guess it must be possible to implement using `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`, can you suggest some implementation?

Comment: Exactly what functionality do you want? The entirety of `StopWatch` or just a portion of it? Maybe some context as to what `StopWatch` is and how it works would be helpful since not every C++ developer also knows C#.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious i need "Restart" and "EllapsedMilleseconds"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example that hopefully demonstrates all the things you need to do to create a Stopwatch class. I'll leave the creation that class up to you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    // save some typing
    namespace cr = std::chrono;

    // you can replace this with steady_clock or system_clock
    typedef cr::high_resolution_clock my_clock;

    // get the clock time before operation.
    // note that this is a static function, and
    // we don't actually create a clock object
    auto start_time = my_clock::now();

    // perform some operation
    std::cin.ignore();

    // get the clock time after the operation
    auto end_time = my_clock::now();

    // get the elapsed time
    auto diff = end_time - start_time;

    // convert from the clock rate to a millisecond clock
    auto milliseconds = cr::duration_cast<cr::milliseconds>(diff);

    // get the clock count (i.e. the number of milliseconds)
    auto millisecond_count = milliseconds.count();

    std::cout << millisecond_count << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thanks, i just hoped that some library class already wraps high_resolution_clock such way