# Why C# is faster than C++ in MS-Word automation

Tags: c#, c++, .net, performance, ms-word

I wrote a little test to compare C# to C++ how long it takes for everyone to do the same action 1000 times. The action is get `Pages.Count`.

This is the test code:

```
public void Main()
{
    TestCppVsCs();
}

[DllImport("WordWithCpp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)]
extern static long Test(IntPtr pWordIUnknown);

private void TestCppVsCs()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Cpp: {TestCpp()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"C#:  {TestCs()}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private long TestCpp()
{
    var word = GetWordApp();
    return Test(Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(word));
}

private double TestCs()
{
    var word = GetWordApp();

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    // Do the action 1000 times
    for (var I = 1; I <= 1000; I++)
        var Count = word.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Pages.Count;

    stopwatch.Stop();

    return stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
}

public Word.Application GetWordApp()
{
    try
    {
        return Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new Word.Application();
    }
}
```

And that's the C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#import "libid:2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52" \
    rename("RGB", "MSORGB") \
    rename("DocumentProperties", "MSODocumentProperties")
using namespace Office;

#import "libid:0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"
using namespace VBIDE;

#import "libid:00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" \
    rename("ExitWindows", "WordExitWindows") \
    rename("FindText", "WordFindText")

#define DllExport  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23527229/7206675
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
namespace cr = std::chrono;

DllExport LONGLONG Test(IUnknown* iUnknown) {
    
    typedef cr::high_resolution_clock my_clock;    
    auto spWordApp = static_cast<Word::_ApplicationPtr>(iUnknown);
    auto start_time = my_clock::now();

    // Do the action 1000 times
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        auto Count = spWordApp->ActiveDocument->ActiveWindow->ActivePane->Pages->Count;
    }

    // get the clock time after the operation
    auto end_time = my_clock::now();

    // get the elapsed time
    auto diff = end_time - start_time;

    // convert from the clock rate to a millisecond clock
    auto milliseconds = cr::duration_cast<cr::milliseconds>(diff);

    // get the clock count (i.e. the number of milliseconds)
    auto millisecond_count = milliseconds.count();

    return millisecond_count;
}
```

And the result is:

```
Cpp: 2812
C#:  1554.2814
```

What's the explanation, why C++ is twice as slow as C#?

I would expect to see that C++ is faster since MS-Word COM is also written in C++.

I compile both projects on release

The C++ project is in `Win32` platform, and compiled with VS 2019, with this command line:

> /permissive- /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Qspectre /Zi /Gm-
> /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D
> "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE"
> /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /FC
> /Fa"Release" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release" /Fp"Release\WordWithCpp.pch"
> /diagnostics:column

The .Net project is `4.6.2` Framework version, and `x86` target CPU.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information for a question about performance. e.g. How are you compiling and building both sources? What optimization flags are you using? Your testing seems to show timings for a single run. You'll need to do many runs, and average across them, to account for caching, etc.

Comment: @cigien Is there enough information now?

Comment: @cigien What do you mean "timings for a single run", The test is done in a loop that ran 1000 times.

Comment: No, I don't think so. At least, I don't know how to answer this question without additional information. I haven't voted to close the question myself, but I think other users might, if you don't provide additional context.

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't see the 1000 loops. However, that is still only measuring a single execution of the *programs*. You might want to run the programs themselves multiple times, and average the results.

Comment: I would not be surprised if Microsoft's C++ is sub-optimal. Microsoft prefers developers to use C#, a technology they fully control, instead of C++ which is an international standard that they don't (mostly) control.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik *(mostly)*? Nice ;)

Comment: Indeed, @cigien, the hot flaming garbage that coroutines are, were entirely Microsoft-backed, to pollute the C++ standard with an arcane pseudo-multithreaded API whose only reason for existence is because it doesn't suck on MS-Windows, while real execution thread suck major wind, over there. Look up who drafted the spec for coroutines. Guess which C++ compiler promptly implemented them, tout-de-suite. You get one guess.

Comment: I'm surprised that `auto Count = spWordApp->ActiveDocument->ActiveWindow->ActivePane->Pages->Count` isn't a noop

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah, fascinating. I haven't been following any of the coroutines proposals/features at all, so I haven't read any of the motivations behind the design. I'll make sure to check out the authors though, thanks for the tip :) Yeah, probably implemented *before* the proposal, to boot :p

Comment: Well, if you can't beat them, embrace and extend them.

Comment: @user4581301 Indeed. I'm sure there are compromises that can be made that'll make everyone reasonably happy. Though Sam doesn't seem thrilled about this one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ is hiding a fair amount of magic behind the `#import`, `auto` and `->`. The corresponding magic in C# and the CLR might be a bit smarter. The Office interfaces are generally `IDispatch` interfaces, and so there is plenty of opportunity to cache the lists of `DispId` and similar information gathered along the way. It's a deep rabbit hole if you start to chase the details. 1579 pages of [Adam Nathan's .NET and COM book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003AYZB7U) is just a start. For COM interop scenarios (and in general), performance would not be a reason to prefer C++ over .NET, in my opinion.

Comment: `->` is just `// Allows this class to be used as the interface itself.
    Interface* operator->() const
    {
        if (m_pInterface)
        {
            return m_pInterface;
        }
        _com_issue_error(E_POINTER);
    }`